# What's the meaning of "uao"?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

I'm in a group chat with some Italian people and they always say "uao". I already search a lot on Google but wasn't able to find anything about it. Does someone can tell me what that means?

Comment: Rather than “on Google”, next time you might want to look up something in actual dictionaries and other resources, for instance [those listed in our Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online).

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an Italianized spelling of "wow", very likely. From [this online dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/uao):

> uàu (o uào) interiez. – Nel linguaggio dei fumetti, adattamento fonetico e grafico della voce onomatopeica angloamer. wow (v.).

By the way, I suggest that you always include some context (one or two sentences) in your questions about a translation; it's often difficult to understand a single word with certainty without context!

Comment: It was also the name of a brand of biscuits 